# C++ std::function variable with varying arguments

Tags: c++, c++11

In my callback system I want to store `std::function` (or something else) with varying arguments.

Example:

1. I want to call `void()`
2. I want to call `void(int, int)`

I want 1) and 2) to be stored in the same variable and choose what to call in actuall call

```
FunctionPointer f0;
FunctionPointer f2;

f0();
f2(4, 5);
```

Is it possible to do something like this? Or I have to create several "FuntionPointer" templates based on input arguments count.

**EDIT**

Is it possible to utilize std::bind somehow for this task? With std::bind I can have `std::function<void()> f = std::bind(test, 2, 5);`

**EDIT 2**

Practical use case: I have a trigger system and I want to assign funtion pointers to actions, so when action happen, function is called.
Pseudo-code sample:

```
structure Trigger 
{
   Function f;
}

Init:
  Trigger0.f = pointer to some function ()
  Trigger1.f = pointer to some function (a, b)

Input: 
  Find Trigger by input
  if (in == A) Trigger.f();
  else Trigger.f(10, 20)
```

or if possible

```
Input:
  Find Trigger by input
  if (in == A) f = bind(Trigger.f);
  else f = bind(Trigger.f, 10, 20);
  f()
```

Comment: [C++11 variadic std::function parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9242234/1708801) seems a close match.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour That only moves the problem to template, the variable type can not be the same and hold both functions at once. I can not make std::vector of different functions for example

Comment: Can you provide an actual practical use case?  Without a practical use case, answers are just throwing syntax against the wall.  "Something like that" is extremely vague, and that is about as specific as you get.  You then go on about `bind`, which is nothing like the "something like that" example.  Again, a practical use case/problem to solve cuts through all that noise.  That means an actual concrete problem you run into when writing software.  I can think up 10 answers that might answer your question, but which one would help you depends on *what you actually want to do*.

Comment: Please look at my latest answer. If it doesn't satisfy your needs, could you explain me why (comment under my last answer)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, if you can use RTTI, you can define a `MultiFuncObject` like this, and you can easily bind other functions. Also, you can easily call them. But unfortunately, this approach only works for a limited number of arguments. But actually `boost::bind` also supports limited number of arguments (by default 9). So you can extend this class to satisfy your needs.

Before giving you the source of `MultiFuncObject`, I want to show you how you can use it. It takes an template argument to be used as return type. You can bind new functions with `+=` operator. With some template magic, the class distinguishes differences between bound functions with same count of arguments with at least one different argument type.

You need C++11, because `MultiFuncObject` uses `std::unordered_map` and `std::type_index`.

Here is usage:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void _1() {
  cout << "_1" << endl;
}

void _2(char x) {
  cout << "_2" << " " << x << endl;
}

void _3(int x) {
  cout << "_3" << " " << x << endl;
}

void _4(double x) {
  cout << "_4" << " " << x << endl;
}

void _5(int a, int b) {
  cout << "_5" << " " << a << " " << b << endl;
}

void _6(char a, int b) {
  cout << "_6" << " " << a << " " << b << endl;
}

void _7(int a, int b, int c) {
  cout << "_7" << " " << a << " " << b << " " << c << endl;
}

int main() {
  MultiFuncObject<void> funcs;
  funcs += &_1;
  funcs += &_2;
  funcs += &_3;
  funcs += &_4;
  funcs += &_5;
  funcs += &_6;
  funcs += &_7;
  funcs();
  funcs('a');
  funcs(56);
  funcs(5.5);
  funcs(2, 5);
  funcs('q', 6);
  funcs(1, 2, 3);
  return 0;
}
```

I hope this is close to what you want. Here is the source of `MultiFuncObject`:

```
#include <typeinfo>
#include <typeindex>
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;

template <typename R>
class MultiFuncObject {
  unordered_map<type_index, void (*)()> m_funcs;
public:

  MultiFuncObject<R> operator +=( R (* f)() ) {
    m_funcs[typeid( R() )] = (void (*)()) f;
    return *this;
  }

  template <typename A1>
  MultiFuncObject<R> operator +=( R (* f)(A1) ) {
    m_funcs[typeid( R(A1) )] = (void (*)()) f;
    return *this;
  }

  template <typename A1, typename A2>
  MultiFuncObject<R> operator +=( R (* f)(A1, A2) ) {
    m_funcs[typeid( R(A1, A2) )] = (void (*)()) f;
    return *this;
  }

  template <typename A1, typename A2, typename A3>
  MultiFuncObject<R> operator +=( R (* f)(A1, A2, A3) ) {
    m_funcs[typeid( R(A1, A2, A3) )] = (void (*)()) f;
    return *this;
  }

  R operator()() const
  {
    unordered_map<type_index, void (*)()>::const_iterator it = m_funcs.find(typeid( R() ));
    if (it != m_funcs.end()) {
      R (*f)() = ( R (*)() )(it->second);
      (*f)();
    }
  }

  template <typename A1>
  R operator()(A1 a1) const
  {
    unordered_map<type_index, void (*)()>::const_iterator it = m_funcs.find(typeid( R(A1) ));
    if (it != m_funcs.end()) {
      R (*f)(A1) = ( R (*)(A1) )(it->second);
      (*f)(a1);
    }
  }

  template <typename A1, typename A2>
  R operator()(A1 a1, A2 a2) const
  {
    unordered_map<type_index, void (*)()>::const_iterator it = m_funcs.find(typeid( R(A1, A2) ));
    if (it != m_funcs.end()) {
      R (*f)(A1, A2) = ( R (*)(A1, A2) )(it->second);
      (*f)(a1, a2);
    }
  }

  template <typename A1, typename A2, typename A3>
  R operator()(A1 a1, A2 a2, A3 a3) const
  {
    unordered_map<type_index, void (*)()>::const_iterator it = m_funcs.find(typeid( R(A1, A2, A3) ));
    if (it != m_funcs.end()) {
      R (*f)(A1, A2, A3) = ( R (*)(A1, A2, A3) )(it->second);
      (*f)(a1, a2, a3);
    }
  }

};
```

It stores different function prototypes using `std::unordered_map` with keys of `std::type_index` and values of `void (*)()`. When needed, the correct function is retrieved using that map.

[Here is the working example](http://ideone.com/g2mdq4)

Comment: I have improved your solution with variadic templates and now it is almost what I wanted (only concern now is RTTI, but hey, I can live with that, since I am not having real-time app)

Comment: @MartinPerry That's great! I am not familiar to variadic templates, so if you can send a link to the improved code; that would be great! :)

Comment: I have also done some measurements of performance: http://www.perry.cz/clanky/functions.html

Answer (score 13):

`std::function<void()>` and `std::function<void(int, int)>` are two absolutely distinct types. You need some sort of union functionality (or polymorphism) to store an object of an unknown type.

If you can use Boost, you could easily do this with [`boost::variant`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/variant/):

```
// Declaration:
boost::variant<std::function<void()>, std::function<void(int, int)> > f;

// Calling, explicit:
if (fContainsNullary()) {
  boost::get<std::function<void()>>(f)();
} else {
  boost::get<std::function<void(int, int)>>(f)(4, 5);
}
```

It is up to you to provide the logic of `fContainsNullary()`. Alternatively, you can use the variant's own stored knowledge of value type by using a visitor:

```
struct MyVisitor : boost::static_visitor<void>
{
  result_type operator() (const std::function<void()> &a) {
    a();
  }

  result_type operator() (const std::function<void(int, int)> &a) {
    a(4, 5);
  }
};

// Calling, via visitor:
boost::apply_visitor(MyVisitor(), f);
```

If Boost is not an option, you can hand-craft a suitable `union` for much the same purpose.

Answer (score 6):

The following solution might work for you (I'm not sure that the code is absolutely correct here):

Create a wrapper for `std::function` with virtual destructor to enable using dynamic cast

```
class function_wrapper_base
{
    virtual ~function_wrapper_base();
}

template <class... Args>
class function_wrapper
    : public function_wrapper_base
{
public:
   std::function<void, Args...> f;
   ...
};
```

Then create a class `variant_function_holder`

```
class variant_function_holder
{
    std::unique_ptr<function_wrapper_base> f;
    ...
    template <class... Args>
    void operator()(Args&&... args)
    {
        function_wrapper<std::decay<Args>::type...> * g = dynamic_cast<function_wrapper<std::decay<Args>::type...>>(f.get());

        if (g == nullptr)
        {
            // ToDo
        }

        g->f(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
};
```

Comment: Care: a call with a c-string literal (`const char*`) will fail (for the `dynamic_cast`) for `function_wrapper<std::string>`...

Answer (score 4):

C++11 to the rescue!

If you can generalize your function to a functor object taking no arguments, then you can call it with any lambda.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class F>
void call_it(F&& f)
{
    f();
}

int main()
{
    int x = 50, y = 75;

    call_it([] () { cout << "Hello!\n"; });
    call_it([x,y] () { cout << x << " + " << y << " = " << x + y << '\n';});


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How is this different from using just `std::function<void()>`?

Comment: `std::function` has a bit of storage overhead, that can be removed by binding directly to the closure type.  The practical difference is negligible, but may be important depending on use case.

Answer (score 2):

If `std::function` is not necessary for you, you can create a proxy class.

```
class fn_t {
public:
  typedef void (*fn_1_t)();
  typedef void (*fn_2_t)(int, int);
  fn_1_t fn_1;
  fn_2_t fn_2;
  fn_t operator=(fn_1_t func_1) { fn_1 = func_1; return *this; }
  fn_t operator=(fn_2_t func_2) { fn_2 = func_2; return *this; }
  void operator()() { (*fn_1)(); }
  void operator()(int a, int b) { (*fn_2)(a, b); }
};

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void first() {
  cout << "first" << endl;
}

void second(int a, int b) {
  cout << "second " << a << " : " << b << endl;
}

int main() {
  fn_t f;
  f = &first;
  f = &second;
  f();
  f(5, 4);
  return 0;
}
```

Class `fn_t` automatically works with two prototypes you want, assigns automatically needed one, and it can call functions with both prototypes by overlading `()` operator with appropriate parameters.

You may want to check for validity of function pointers `fn_1` and `fn_2` but I didn't include this checking for minimality.

The advantage of this is that you only need C++ and not even STL and Boost.

Comment: works only for the two examples though. What if he suddenly needs 3 parameters? Or the two of different types etc.? He would need to write a big mess of a class then.

Comment: @pfannkuchen_gesicht I interpreted the question as this "I have two **well defined** function prototypes, I want to store pointers to functions with those prototypes in only one object and call them easily using one object."

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are fine but I want to show my solution as well.

It's a [small header](https://github.com/R3AL/exBind/blob/master/ex_bind.hpp) with which you can "elongate" function signatures.
This allows you to do this (extract from the [github example](https://github.com/R3AL/exBind/blob/master/example.cpp)):

```
int foo_1p(int a);
int foo_2p(int a, int b);
int foo_3p(int a, int b, int c);
int foo_4p(int a, int b, int c, int d);
int foo_5p(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e);
int foo_6p(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e, int f);
int foo_7p(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e, int f, std::string g);
...

int main()
{
   std::unordered_map<std::string, std::function<int(int, int, int, int, int, int, std::string)>> map;
   map["foo_1p"] = ex::bind(foo_1p, ph, ph, ph, ph, ph, ph);
   map["foo_2p"] = ex::bind(foo_2p, ph, ph, ph, ph, ph);
   map["foo_3p"] = ex::bind(foo_3p, ph, ph, ph, ph);
   map["foo_4p"] = ex::bind(foo_4p, ph, ph, ph);
   map["foo_5p"] = ex::bind(foo_5p, ph, ph);
   map["foo_6p"] = ex::bind(foo_6p, ph);
   map["foo_7p"] = foo_7p;

   for (const auto& f : map)
   {
       std::cout << f.first << " = " << f.second(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, "101") << std::endl;
   }
}
```