# How does a list of std::function with variable arguments work

Tags: c++, c++11, std, std-function

I have a list of functions declared as `std::list< std::function< void()>> funcList;`
As far as I understand `std::function< void()>` is different from (for example) `std::function< int(int)>`. So then how is registerCB accepting arguments with varying signatures of `std::function`.

```
std::list<std::function<void()>> funcList;
void registerCB(std::function<void()>&& f) {
    funcList.push_back(f);
}
registerCB(std::bind(func1, 1));        
registerCB(std::bind(func2,"Test"));
registerCB(std::bind(func3));
```

where func1, func2, func3 are 3 functions with different argument list.

registerCB expects an argument of type function, so does funcList.

I saw a similar post - [C++ std::function variable with varying arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32823046/c-stdfunction-variable-with-varying-arguments)

But I could not find the explanation to the above question.

Comment: If you provide all of the parameters (binding the parameters to the function), the bound function acts like it has no parameters (because it uses the bound ones) and meets the `void()` requirement. This is probably what you've run into, but without details on `func`s 1, 2, and 3, it is impossible to confirm.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks. 
func s 1, 2, and 3 just have cout statements. 
void func1(int a){
    cout << "Calling func1: "<<a<<endl; 
}

void func2(string a) {
   cout << "Calling func2: "<<a<<endl;  
}
void func3() {
    cout << "Calling func3\n";
}

Comment: Solution - try `std::list<std::function<void(std::any)>> funcList;` on c++17

Comment: Groovy, flamethrower. That confirms it. Bryan's answer has the right of it, but a more detailed/precise answer may come along. There could be some nasty little detail I don't know about. I pretty much stopped using `bind` a few years ago when someone here pointed me at [Lambda Expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda). Set up the captures right and most of the time they can do the same thing with a lot less overhead.

Answer (score 2):

This is because otherwise `std::bind` wouldn't work.

The purpose of `std::bind` is to generate a forwarding call wrapper for a function which in this case it does.

As all of the required arguments are bound to each function, each of the bound functions signatures match the `std::function<void()>&& f` signature.

With generic lambdas introduced in c++14 there is very little use for `std::bind`.

Wrapping each function with a lambda would make your code be more performant,
easier to understand and may allow you to drop the `<functional>` header for better compile times
not to mention the ability to add additional logic on top of your called function.

For more information, see
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda