# Storing C++ lambdas with variable arguments

Tags: c++, generics, lambda, callback, variadic

I would like to create a construction with following mechanics:

```
void some_func1();
void somt_func2(int, float = 3.14f);
enum { SIGNAL0, SIGNAL1 };

// connect
int con0 = connect(SIGNAL0, some_func1);
int con1 = connect(SIGNAL1, some_func2);
int con2 = connect(SIGNAL0, []{ /*some code*/ });
int con3 = connect(SIGNAL1, [](int, float){ /*some code*/ });

// invoke
invoke(SIGNAL0);
invoke(SIGNAL1, 123, 3.14f);

// would even be nice to be able to do this:
invoke(SIGNAL1, 123);

//the second float parameter gets default argument
// (probably not possible because of lambda can't have default args?)
```

How would the functions connect(int, ...?), invoke(int, ...?) and stored callback type look like?

Comment: I think this is similar to what I was looking for:
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32823046/c-stdfunction-variable-with-varying-arguments)

Comment: The do not present any possible solution.

Comment: The closest solution is: [link](http://www.perry.cz/clanky/functions.html)
But still it does not work for me.

What I basically need is a way to store any std::funcion in a pointer and cast to correct type when invoking.

Comment: I'm guessing you've already looked at [boost.signals2](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/doc/html/signals2.html)?