# Passing function into function with std::function and template argument

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, type-inference, std-function

I am trying to pass a pointer to the predicate function into the `Foo` and `Bar` functions.
The `Bar` function works correctly, but the `Foo` function raises a compile-time error:

> error: no matching function for call to `Foo<int>(bool (&)(int))`

Why does the compiler raise an error?
Is there any difference between `Foo`'s and `Bar`'s template arguments types after `Args`' unpacking?

```cpp
#include <functional>

bool predicate(int a) {
    return (a > 5);
}

// sizeof...(Args) == 1 and I suppose it is int
template<typename... Args>
void Foo(std::function<bool(Args...)> predicate) {
    // clang: note: candidate template ignored:
    //        could not match 'function<bool (int, type-parameter-0-0...)>' 
    //        against 'bool (*)(int)'
}

template<typename Args>
void Bar(std::function<bool(Args)> predicate) {

}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    // gcc: error: no matching function for call to
    //      'Foo<int>(bool (&)(int))'
    Foo<int>(predicate);
    Bar<int>(predicate);
    
    return 0;
}
```

[See Compiler Explorer for a live example](https://godbolt.org/z/46EzPY).

I also tried to change the `Foo` function a little and it works somehow:

```cpp
template<typename... Args>
void Foo(bool(*predicate)(Args...)) {
  std::function<bool(Args...)> func(predicate);
}
```

I want to have `std::function` type argument in the `Foo` function, but I don't know how to do it

Answer (score 1):

The error is because the exact type of `std::function` is not same as `predicate`. To get around this, you can explicitly call the constructor of `std::function`:

```
int main() {
    Foo<int>( std::function<bool(int){predicate} );
    //OR
    Foo<int>( {predicate} );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I find it perplexing that you have to call the constructor at all though. `std::function` can be implicitly constructed from function pointers. Any idea why this implicit conversion is not possible here?

Comment: @J.Schultke Not entirely sure, it works with normal `std::function<bool(...)>` variable but doesn't work if it is a function parameter. There is a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9242234/c11-variadic-stdfunction-parameter but no clear answer unfortunately.